# How to get Vim to show git status in the statusline?

Tags: statusline, git

I want to show the git status in the vim statusline, but I can't find any advice on how to do that.

The output of `git status -s` would be fine, or alternatively a single field readout indicating whether there are any outstanding changes, like this:
[Clean]
or
[Changes]

It would probably be sensible to refresh the display whenever the current buffer was saved to disk.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! If you use fugitive, you could always use `:G`; it also provides `fugitive#statusline` which is slightly more than just the branch info. There are plugins that show information in the status column (git gutterline or some such). Lastly, you could do something like `systemlist('git status -s')` and use the results. I'll leave it to somebody with better design thoughts to put the pieces together, though

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way would be to call `git` inside `%{}` like so:

```
let &statusline = '%{substitute(system("git status -s"), "\n", " ", "g")}'
```

Anything inside `%{}` get evaluated as an expression, and here we call `git status -s` with `system()` and replace newlines with a space, resulting in a statusline like:

```
## repl  M db.go ?? zxc
```

---

There's a huge problem with this approach though: it gets run on every screen update, meaning you're forever running `git` commands. A better approach would be to only run the `git` command on certain strategic events, capture the result in a variable, and display the variable.

```
augroup gitstatusline
    au!

    autocmd BufEnter,FocusGained,BufWritePost *
        \ let b:git_status = substitute(system("git status -s"), "\n", " ", "g")
augroup end

let &statusline = '%{get(b:, "git_status", "")}'
```

So here we record the git status in a buffer-local `b:git_status` variable, which gets updated when we enter the buffer. This is displayed with `get()` for safety in case it's not set yet.

You can add some other events as well if you want more frequent updates, such as `CursorHold`. You can see [`:help autocmd-events-abc`](https://vimhelp.org/autocmd.txt.html#autocmd-events-abc) for a list of all supported events.

---

There is still a problem with this: the command always runs in the current directory, rather than in the buffer's directory. So `:e ../other-project/file` will give you the wrong results. This may not be an issue for everyone, but to fix that you can use something like:

```
autocmd BufEnter,FocusGained,BufWritePost *
    \ let b:git_status = substitute(
        \ system(printf("cd %s && git status -s", expand('%:p:h:S'))),
        \ "\n", " ", "g")
```

---

You can probably also improve on the formatting of this message; displaying all of `git status -s` in the statusline probably isn't always the most convenient as it can get rather long, but that's what you asked for :-) The easiest way to check if a directory is clean or not is probably checking if the output of `git status --porcelain` is blank:

```
augroup gitstatusline
    au!

    autocmd BufEnter,FocusGained,BufWritePost *
        \ let b:git_clean = system(printf("cd %s && git status --porcelain 2>/dev/null", expand('%:p:h:S'))) is# ''
augroup end

let &statusline = '%{get(b:, "git_clean", "") ? "[clean]" : "[changed]"}'
```

But you can use any combination of commands and/or parse the output of the git commands in VimScript. you could display `[branchname: 2 changed, 5 new, 6 deleted]` as well, but I'll leave building a command for that as an exercise for the reader :-)

---

As mentioned in the comments, you can also use fugitive which includes some helpful helper functions which do pretty much the same as the above. But if you're looking for a simple "no-plugin" approach to include the output of `git` commands (or any other shell command or expensive function) then this is the general approach.

Comment: Awesome answer, look forward to trying it. I find Vim script impenetrable myself. There is no love so true as the programmer's love for punctuation marks. The expand('%:p:h:S') looks like pure magic to me.

Comment: Hehe, yeah, VimScript is a bit, eh, idiosyncratic @Philip; but I find it's actually not that hard in general. `expand()` can he used to expand some special values: `%` refers to the filename of the current buffer. You can apply modifications to that with `:<x>`, in this case `:p` to get the full path (`foo.vim` → `/home/x/foo.vim`), `:h` to get the head (aka dirname, `/home/x`), and `:S` to shell quote it. It looks a bit "magic", but it's certainly a lot more concise than `shell_quote(dirname(realpath(get_filename())))` or something like that :-)

Comment: You don’t need cd if you use git -C

Comment: @Martin Tournoij One day scientists will research the effect of punctuation marks on the dopaminergic system and sociologists will start speculating how the world might have been if it had been Dickens who had invented the Lambda Calculus, not Alonso Church. Anyhow, this answer does work, though I had to change " to ' and remove spaces in the call to get(). I also added a 2>/dev/null after the git status --porcelain, so that it doesn't interpret error messages as a true value - so that in a non-git-controlled directory, it doesn't say [changed].

Comment: I think you used `set statusline` instead of `let &statusline` @Philip? The syntax for the 2 is a bit different; `let &` is a bit more flexible than `set` with regards to spaces and the like. And yeah, excluding stderr is better, I'll add it to the answer 

Comment: Right again, I did use `set`. (Why on earth would Vim duplicate let and set like that?).  The `is# ''` is also a magical mystery. I thought it might be inadvertent markup at first, and removed it, but that caused it to break.

Comment: @Philip VimScript is organically grown since the 1970s. `set` is "special syntax" for settings, whereas `let` is more generic syntax for setting variables in general, and with `let &name` you can set a setting. I don't know the history or why this works the way it works  `==` does automatic type conversions like PHP/JS, whereas `is` doesn't. e.g. `0 == '0'` is true and `0 is '0'` isn't. `==` and `is` behaviour depends on the setting of `ignorecase`, whereas `is#` and `==#` are always case-insensitive (and `==? and is? are always case insensitive). Not needed here, but I use it out of habit.

Comment: Actually, after writing all of this out maybe VimScript is a bit harder than I thought; it's just that I'm used to it haha. A lot of this probably has to do with backwards compatibility: `set` was already in the original vi for settings, and re-using that for generic variable assignment would probably break stuff, so `let` was added, and then later `let &` for settings as well. Changing the semantics of `set` would break people's vimrc, so you can't really do that.

Comment: Yeah, it's too much for me - and I'm one of the ones who wasn't phased by pointers to pointers back in the C++ days. Anyway, thanks very much. @D. Ben Knoble, the `git -C` works too, thanks.